# Array receives two of the same values

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

Sorry if the code is sloppy, I've only been working with QT for the past couple of weeks. I'm working on a small game while studying, and right now I'm working on when the player buys an item from the shop it will be placed it into the character bag.

The Problem is when I buy the item once, it works fine. But if I delete the item after purchase then repurchase the same item again it will put two of the same item into the array even though I purchased one.

I have 3 files used for this.   `Inventory.cpp`, `GameScreen.cpp`, `Shops.cpp`.

`GameScreen.cpp` is the main file. Here I just initialize everything.

```
void GameScreen::initGame(QString &characterName, QString &characterProfession){
    //PASS CHARACTERNAME AND CHARACTERPROFESSION INTO INVENTORY
    inv.initCharacter(characterName, characterProfession);
    //INIT BAG
    inv.initBag();
    //INIT MONEY
    inv.initMoney();
    //SHOPS INITS
    mos.initShop();
    mos.passMoneyToShop(inv.gold, inv.silver, inv.copper);
}
```

This will open the shop window. The Item connect is apart of my problem.

```
void GameScreen::on_mapOneShopB_clicked()
{
    mos.setModal(true);

    //SEND THE ITEM INTO BAG
    connect(&mos, SIGNAL(getItemFromMapOneShop(const QString&)), &inv, SLOT(bagAddElement(const QString&)));

    mos.show();
    mos.exec();
}
```

Moving into `Shops.cpp`. I use polymorphism in this file and that's the reason why you see `MapOneShop::` instead of `Shops::`. Sorry about the confusion. But moving on, I hit the button and it subtracts the item price from my amount of gold.

```
void MapOneShop::on_buyB_clicked()
{
    //ONLY WORKS IF I HIT THE ITEM NAME COLUMN THEN HIT BUY
    gold -= itemPrice[ui->treeWidget->currentColumn()];

    //UPDATE INFORMATION
    updateInformationVAndMoneyAfterBuy();

}
```

It then moves into `updateInformationVAndMoneyAfterBuy();` which checks that I spent money, and If I did it will emit the item I need. I just emit back to `GameScreen.cpp` inside of `void GameScreen::on_mapOneShopB_clicked()` and pass them into `Inventory.cpp`.

```
void MapOneShop::updateInformationVAndMoneyAfterBuy()
{
    //UPDATE INFORMATIONV FIRST TO CHECK MONEY CHANGES

    if(goldCheck != gold)
    {
        emit getUpdatedMoneyFromShop(gold, silver, copper);

        //ITEM NAME IS WHERE I STORE THE NAMES OF THE ITEMS
        emit getItemFromMapOneShop(this->itemName[ui->treeWidget->currentColumn()]);
    }
}
```

Now moving into `Inventory.cpp`. When the item gets passed into `bagAddElement` after deleting then repurchasing, I get two of the same items even though only 1 should be passed in. I am using a dynamic array for this. Below I will also show the `void Inventory::on_deleteB_clicked`, `void Inventory::bagDeleteAt` and also `void Inventory::bagLWPrint` functions. The `items` value is my array holding the shopItem strings.

```
void Inventory::bagAddElement(const QString& shopItem)
{
    //I USE THIS TO CHECK THE VALUE shopItem.
    qDebug()<<"bagAddElement: " << shopItem;

    //IF THE CURRENT POSITION IN THE BAG
    //IS BIGGER THAN THE CURRENT SIZE
    //IT WILL INCREASE THE BAG FOR US
    if(nrOfEl >= bagSize)
    {
        bagExpand();
    }

    //CHECK FOR VALUES INSIDE ARRAY AND CHECK IF THEY ARE NULL
    //IF SO, IT WILL ADD THE ITEM INTO THE NULL POSITION
    for(int i = 0; i < bagSize; i++)
    {
        if(items[i] == nullptr)
        {
            nrOfEl = i;
            items[nrOfEl++] = shopItem;
            break;
        }
    }

    //UPDATE WIDGET LIST
    bagLWPrint();
}
```

Here I pass the currently selected row value inside `bagLW` and pass it into `void Inventory::bagDeleteAt`.

```
void Inventory::on_deleteB_clicked()
{
    //BagLW IS A LIST WIDGET
    bagDeleteAt(bagLW->currentRow());
}
```

Now we look for the what's inside `items[row]` and set it to nullptr. Then we go into `void Inventory::bagLWPrint`.

```
void Inventory::bagDeleteAt(int row)
{
    if(items[row] == nullptr)
    {
        //IF THE ITEM IS ALREADY NULL WILL PRINT A MESSAGE
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Bag","No item in that slot");
    }
    else
    {
        //SET CURRENTLY SELECTED ITEM TO NULL
        items[row] = nullptr;
        bagLWPrint();
    }
}
```

I clear `bagLW` and refill it with the updated array.

```
void Inventory::bagLWPrint()
{
    bagLW->clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < bagSize; i++)
    {
        if(items[i] != nullptr)
        {
            bagLW->addItem(items[i]);
        }
        if(items[i] == nullptr)
        {
            bagLW->addItem(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Other notes.

-The item only gets doubled when inserted into `void Inventory::bagAddElement`.
-I tried adding another item inside of `void GameScreen::initGame` and it did not double after deleting and re-entering.

Sorry for such a long question. And any help would be much, much appreciated.

```
void Inventory::bagExpand()
{
    //1: INCREASE BAGSPACE
    bagSize *= 2;
    //2: CREATE TEMP ARRAY
    QString *tempItems = new QString[bagSize];
    //3: COPY OVER VALID VALUES FROM OLD ARRAY
    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfEl; i++)
    {
       tempItems[i] = items[i];
    }
    //4: DELETE OLD ARRAY MEMORY
    delete[] items;
    //5: POINT OLD ARRAY POINTER TO NEW ARRAY LOCATION
    items = tempItems;
    //PRINT BAGLW - (UDPATE)
    bagLWPrint();
    qDebug()<<"Bag has increased";
}
```

Comment: Here is a video link for people that want more of a visual - https://youtu.be/g2g-su-vXZM

Comment: Did you already hear about [mcve]? Please, first try to resemble your problem in a [mcve] - exactly only this part you need for to move an item from one container to another, and back, and for  again (as you described). Then, debug it and try to find out yourself what's going wrong. When you feel lost _then_ post this [mcve] with your question. You provided way too much code and I doubt that it's a complete sample I could compile on my site to have a try myself...

Comment: @Scheff No I did not hear about that. And sorry for not knowing about it. I'm sorry that It was too much code. I didn't think that at all. It's only 8 functions with each having less than 10 lines of simple code. And it's all in order as of functionality wise.  I'm sorry again and I'll do better next time. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: A good start for an [mcve] would be a single block of code that does not require UI interaction from you but _does_ provoke the problem. Then you can step through it and verify your assumptions.

Comment: How do `items` and `bagLW` relate to each other? What does `bagExpand` do?

Comment: @Botje The size of the array is 5. Once it reaches 5 it will double in size. `bagLW` updates the TreeWidget with the values inside of `items`.

Comment: @Botje Will do. I guess I will make a minimal reproducible example tomorrow. Sorry about the bad question.

Comment: No worries, it is sometimes hard to pinpoint exactly what information you need so people can help. Be sure to edit _this_ question with your minimal example!

Comment: Heads up. Have seen much worse first questions... ;-)

Comment: @Tommy How does `bagExpand` work? I see a problem that you are expanding the bag although its not necessary (after you deleted an item `nrOfEl` remains unchanged which is also a misleading name since it does not store the actual number of items but the current bad position)

Comment: @Odysseus `bagExpand` multiplies `bagSize` by 2. Then creates a `tempArr` and copies everything from `items` into it in a `for()` loop. After that it deletes `items` and copies everything from `tempArr` into `items`. And Lastly it calls `bagLW` again to update the Tree Widget.

Comment: @Odysseus I was using `nrOfEl` as a position holder to insert new items. If something is inserted at `items[0]` then `nrOfEl` will become 1.

Comment: @Tommy I took your code you just added for `bagExpand` and edited your question but it needs to be unlocked first by another member or you just add it by yourself

Comment: @Odysseus Thanks for doing that for me.

Comment: You connect the `getItemFromMapOneShop` signal on every button click. That means that on first click, you add it once (signal triggered, 1 slot connected). On the second click, you add it twice (signal triggered, 2 slots connected). And so on. You should connect the singal only once, e.g. in the constructor; or disconnect the signal when no longer used

Comment: @king_nak Oh wow that worked! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you connect and re-connect the `getItemFromMapOneShop` signal on every button click. That means that on first click, you add it once (signal triggered, 1 slot connected). On the second click, you add it twice (signal triggered, 2 slots connected). And so on.

`QObject`s manage a list of all connected slots per signal, and call each of them. Connecting a slot multiple times will call it that many times

You should connect the singal only once, e.g. in the constructor; or disconnect the signal when no longer used

As @Andéon Evain pointed out, you could also use [`Qt::UniqueConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). This will not add a duplicate connection if it already exists (considering sender, signal, receiver, slot). That might be useful for cases where it's unknown if already connected; not in your simple case

Comment: You can also give pass Qt::UniqueConnection to connect, to avoid making a duplicate if the connect was already done. In some cases it's justified.
In this case, though, it's probably not the best. No reason to call a connect on every click.